# Spring - Redirect to another view with data binding

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I think this question is quite easy if I know the keyword but I'm new to Spring so I need your help, any editing is appreciated.

This is how I can put and get an object data from a view.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Map model) {
    Member member = new Member(1, "admin", "admin", Boolean.TRUE, null);
    model.put("member", member);
    return "login";
}

// The parameters must be in order @Model, BindingResult, Map
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ProcessForm(@ModelAttribute("member") Member member, BindingResult result, Map model) {
    dao = new JdbcMemberDao(MemberController.dataSource);
    member = (Member) model.get("member");
    Member tmp = dao.getUser(member.getUsername(), member.getPassword());
    if (tmp != null) {
        model.put("member", tmp);
        return "phonelist";
    }
    return "login";
}
```

But what if I have a list of objects so how do I know to get the object I want :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/phonelist", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPhoneList(Map model) {
    List<Phone> phones = dao.getPhones();
    model.put("phones",phones);
    return "phonelist";
}
```

the view of list of objects (using JSTL) :

```
<table id="phoneTable">
    <tr><th id="name">Name</th><th id="brand">Brand</th><th id="price">Price</th></tr>
    <c:forEach items="${phones}" var="phone">
    <tr><td><c:out value="${phone.name}"/></td><td><c:out value="${phone.brand}"/></td><td><c:out value="${phone.price}"/></td></tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

My question is:

1. How can I create a view with link for every object so I can click to a specific item.
2. get the specific item that I've just clicked.

Thanks a billion :)

Comment: can't you create link with a HTML tag?

Comment: @Hoàng Long: that's part is easy, but how spring handle a post clicked by that link, what object will be returned when we don't put a single object in that view ?

Comment: you just need to create an action in controller, with relevant @RequestMapping

Comment: @Hoàng Long: it will be more clear if you answer my question instead of comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed in Spring 3.1 with the new feature called "flash attributes":

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes